# Ubuntu wifi connects and works for 5 minutes then stops working while remaining connected

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wifi, dual-boot, ethernet

I have my 1TB hard drive split even between ubuntu 14.04 and windows 10.

wifi and ethernet work great in windows, and wifi works great in ubuntu--for about five minutes. ethernet doesn't really work at all anymore, but it used to. the icon stays as though i'm connected, but i can't access perform any functions that would require an internet connection.

here's the result from ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1c:39:47:21:2a:d9  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:165 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:165 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:11993 (11.9 KB)  TX bytes:11993 (11.9 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:52:cb:74:e0:53  
      inet addr:192.168.0.13  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::3252:cbff:fe74:e053/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:183 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:190 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:17470 (17.4 KB)  TX bytes:26540 (26.5 KB)
```

for my network adapters:

ETHERNET: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
WIRELESS: Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4 Wireless Network Adapter

Comment: Can you ping your router? Can you ping e.g. stackexchange.com?

Comment: Edit to include results for `iwconfig`

Comment: @Jeremy31 iwconfig results

`eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"BHNTC8715D64AD"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 08:95:2A:61:64:B3   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-27 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:197   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

`

Comment: @Fiximan `ping 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.12 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.12 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
64 bytes from 192.168.0.12: icmp_seq=18997 ttl=64 time=7.56 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.12: icmp_seq=18998 ttl=64 time=43.0 ms
ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available
ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available
19021 packets transmitted, 18588 received, +369 errors, 2% packet loss, time 19856151ms
ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available
ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available
`

Answer (score 4):

Disable wifi power management with

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

Then test the connection to see if it improves

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

According to [wireless.wiki.kernel](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath10k/firmware) , there are two way to get the wifi working:

1) Compile a new kernel version at least the 4.0

or

2) Using [backport](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath10k/backports)

> It is possible to use newer ath10k driver on an older kernel with backports project.
>
> Download latest backports release from [**here**](http://drvbp1.linux-foundation.org/~mcgrof/rel-html/backports/)  and unpack it.
>
> Run defconfig for ath10k:

```
make defconfig-ath10k
```

> Compile backports:

```
make
```

> Install backports:

```
sudo make install
```

> Reboot system and ath10k should load automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Open `/etc/resolv.conf` and check that it contains a valid DNS server (e.g. google):

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Normally when modified you won't need to restart the network manager, as it will detect and apply the changes.

Comment: i believe it has a valid dns server but just in case `CONTENTS OF RESOLV.CONF

# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1

`

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem after changing the wifi router.

The solution that worked for me, was to set the router **wifi mode** to **b/g only**.

Answer (score 0):

For me was a combination of turning off the Power Management for the wlan and removing unused Docker networks:

Get the wlan name with "ifconfig" and:

```
sudo iwconfig <wlan_name> power off
docker network prune
```